# Тестирование встроенным в visual studio методом

Tags: c#, visual-studio, юнит-тесты

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AddCorrectServer()
    {
        init();
        ServerAdd serverAdd = new ServerAdd(listenerContext);
        Assert.AreEqual(serverAdd.Get(), "OK");
    }
```

Пишу проект на C# в Visual Studio. Допустим у меня есть в классе с тестами этот тест. У меня есть класс `ServerAdd` в котором есть метод `Get()` который возвращает строку. Но он у меня private. И вызвать так, как я его хочу(`serverAdd.Get()`), я не могу. Могу ли я не делая метод public как-то вытащить результат его работы для проверки в тесте? Я предполагаю, что класс с тестами это такой же класс как и остальные и не получу я метод по экз. класса если он приватный, но может существует способ не делать все public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов решения данной проблемы:

1. Можно воспользоваться атрибутом [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): соответственно модификаторы доступа всех типов и методов, нуждающихся в тестировании, необходимо изменить на `internal` и дать доступ сборке с тестами, передав в конструктор атрибута её полное имя.
2. Использовать встроенный в MSTest Framework класс [`PrivateObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx), который внутри себя использует рефлексию, для получения доступа к приватным типам и их членам:

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void AddCorrectServer()
   {
       init();
       ServerAdd serverAdd = new ServerAdd(listenerContext);
       PrivateObject pobj = new PrivateObject(serverAdd);

       var result = pobj.Invoke("Get") as string;
       Assert.AreEqual("OK", result);
   }
   ```